# DynamoDB keep track of execution between 2 tables

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, dynamodb-queries

I've a Lambda which makes an API request to a service and get a list of matches for a given identifier.
Once it gets a list of matches it updates a DynamoDB table in the following way:

| requestId (partitionKey) | ID | matches | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid1 | ID1 | [match1,match2, match3...] | FOUND_MATCHES |

For each match in this table, a message is sent to SQS which is listened to by a Lambda. For each match, the Lambda will make a call to a different service and update a table which keeps track of the matches execution.

| Match (partitionKey) | requestId (sortKey + GSI Partition Key) |
| --- | --- |
| match1 | uuid1 |
| match2 | uuid1 |
| ... | ... |
| match10 | uuid1 |

Now given the requestId, I would like to know if there are entries in the 2nd table for all matches.

One option I'm thinking is look up the first table via the requestId and it will give the list of matches, then it will call the 2nd table multiple times via the primary key, sortKey combination and compile a result. The other option is instead of looking up via primary key/sort key for 2nd table, it will look via a GSI Parition key on the requestId column and get all the matches at once (in a paginated list).

I would like to expose this operation via an API call, and I'm wondering if I'll run into APIG 30 seconds timeout (I know I'll need to run some experiments with my dataset, but just wanted to see if there are other options I can consider before doing this). If number of matches exceed say 50,000. And each get call roughly takes 20ms, it will take about 50,000 * 20 = 1000 seconds which is way more than APIG limit. Maybe batch call might help a bit, but not sure there is much room there.

Essentially I would like to update the status in the first table from `FOUND_MATCHES` to `ALL_MATCHES_PROCESSED`.

1. Ideal option is automatically the state gets updated
2. A Get status API essentially triggers the calculation and updates the state (Maybe make this async to get past the 30seconds APIG limitation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do it like this, since I'm a fan of the single table design pattern:

| PK | SK | type | attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `REQ#<id>` | `META` | REQUEST | matches: [a,b,c]; unprocessed_matches: 3; status: FOUND_MATCHES |
| `REQ#<id>` | `M#a` | MATCH | result |
| `REQ#<id>` | `M#b` | MATCH | result |
| `REQ#<id>` | `M#c` | MATCH | result |

Whenever a new request comes in, you write a `REQUEST` to the table with the matches and an `unprocessed_matches` attribute that counts all matches.

Then you have a Lambda function "stream-processor" that listens to the stream of that table.
When a **new** `REQUEST` item shows up (no old image present), it creates the tasks in your SQS queue.

The worker process on your SQS queue then calls the 3rd party API and records the result.
The result is then written to the table through a **transaction** with two items:

1. An `UpdateItem` call, that decrements the unprocessed_matches value for the request id by one.
2. A `PutItem` call, that creates the `MATCH` item.

The transaction here is important, you want this to be an all or nothing operation.

Your stream-processor lambda then has a second job.
Whenever there is update to a `REQUEST` item, it should check, if `unprocessed_matches <= 0 and status = FOUND_MATCHES`.
When that's the case, it should update the `REQUEST` item and set the status to `ALL_MATCHES_PROCESSED`.

Your original Lambda that made the first request can periodically poll the status of the item in the table.

This design also let's you easily get everything about a request by a simple `Query` to the partition key with the request ID.

**You should be aware that there is a 400KB item size limit in DynamoDB, depending on how long your matches list gets, this might become a problem.**

Comment: thanks. This is an interesting take. However it looks like in your solution, the entire batch of matches is done at once, which may not work for me. Also yes I'll the hit the dynamo size limit and I'm planning to store the list in s3 and just a link in the table

Comment: "Then you have a Lambda function "stream-processor" that listens to the stream of that table. When a new REQUEST item shows up (no old image present), it creates the tasks in your SQS queue." --> The idea is that each match get's put as a task into the queue. The worker that reads can process these individually or in batches, there is no need to process all of these as a single batch.

Comment: I see. However with my list of matches essentially in s3, and this being a fan out approach, there could be multiple writers to one row. Wouldn't that cause conditional exceptions? It essentially does a get and then put right?

Comment: That's not a problem if you use the update expression to decrement the value, DynamoDB takes care of that for you in the background.

Comment: Could you point me to this decrement expression. I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.IncrementAndDecrement

Comment: Thank you so much. Last question and I know I'll have to try with my work loads and dataset, but with so many lambdas trying to update all at once to same record isn't there a risk of dynamodb puts failing or somehow ddb is able to magically handle it?

Comment: If you have enough WCUs/RCUs this works fine, but that's also why I suggested the use of a transaction :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just curious if you know any other way to do without transactions?

Comment: You could also do a read and then a conditional write - the pattern is called [Optimistic Locking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html)